# ZK - Accessing GUI elements from ItemRenderer

Tags: java, textbox, zk, itemrenderer

I am having problems accessing GUI elements outside the model class in my ZK project. I have a ListItemRenderer that renders the data and the position of the corresponding model when I click on an element in a list box, but my instance is permanently null when I access the article class again, as well as all GUI elements that I connect when I create the class for the first time (via getFellow ()). Is that even the right approach? Alternatively, could I add a listener to a variable that reloads the text box if it is changed? Thanks for every hint, I've already had several frustrating hours behind me and hope the code snippet is enough.

ZUL:

```
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" root="./winArticles"?>
<window id="winArticles" title="Looking for Evidence" width="1100px"  height="880px" 
border="normal" use="xxx.Articles" closable="true" sizable="false">
...
 <listbox id="artikel_output" width="100%" height="" multiple="true"  
          checkmark="true"   vflex="true" nonselectableTags="*">
 <listhead>
      <listheader label="Artikel"/> 
 </listhead> 
 </listbox> 
...
      <div   vflex="1">
            <textbox style="font-size:50px" 
                     id="tb_article_abstract"
                     multiline="true"/>
     </div>
...
</window>
```

Model :

```
public class Articles extends Window implements AfterCompose, 
IGenericDomainValueSelectorActions, IUpdateModal, IGenericListActions {
     private static Articles instance;

public Articles() { }

public static Articles getInstance() { 
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Articles();
    }
    logger.debug("Instance getInstance " + instance.getId());
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void afterCompose() {
    instance = new Articles(); 
    tb_article_abstract = (Textbox) getFellow("tb_article_abstract");  
  ...}
```

Initializing the listbox renderer:

```
public void fillListBoxWithArticles(final Listbox lb, List<Article> articles) {  
    if (articles.size() == 0) {
        lb.appendChild((Component) articles.get(0));
    } 
    lb.setItemRenderer(new ArticleItemRenderer());        
    lb.setCheckmark(true);
    lb.setMultiple(true); 
    ListModelList<Article> lml_articles = new ListModelList<Article>(articles);
    lml_articles.setMultiple(true);
    lb.setModel(lml_articles); 
    lb.focus();
}
```

If a list box element has been selected, display an attribute of it in a text box, but the textbox is always null...

```
public void setArticleToInfobox(Article selectedArticle, int selectedIndex) {
    this.selectedArticle = selectedArticle;  
    // tb_article_abstract = null 
    tb_article_abstract.setValue(selectedArticle.getAbstract_full());
    tb_article_abstract.invalidate();
}}
```

The ItemRenderer is getting the data (and the index) of the selected Item:

```
public class ArticleItemRenderer implements ListitemRenderer<Article> {  
@Override
public void render(Listitem item, Article data, int index) throws Exception {

    item.appendChild(new Listcell(data.getArticletitle() + ", "  ); 
    item.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new EventListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {     
            EvidenceBasedArticles.getInstance().setArticleToInfobox(data, item.getIndex());
        }});}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making some crucial faults here.

```
public static Articles getInstance() { 
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Articles();
    }
    logger.debug("Instance getInstance " + instance.getId());
    return instance;
}
```

This will never work good, you are developing a web application.
This means that 2 users at the same time can have only 1 instance, however your Article is allocated to a specific Desktop, so 1 user will have problems.

What's wrong with :

```
lb.setItemRenderer(new ArticleItemRenderer(tb_article_abstract));
```

Your renderer has a new instance for this specific class, so it's bound to the correct desktop.
As long you don't remove that item from the DOM, this would be no problem to do.

Comment: shame on me, i guess it is obvious that i am new in developing web application ;). thank you very much for your understandable explanation, works fine.